# Is there any way we can download everything that is required to create a react app so we can use it to create react app offline?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I always create react app templates when i am online so that i can use them when i am offline, but is there any way we can download everything at once and use it to create react-app again and again offline?
I try to copy the react-app which i create but making a copy takes forever, the speed of copying goes to 40KB/s , seems like devs dont want to save us some bandwidth?
I know devs want us to use latest version but that can be done in prompting us by notification about latest version instead of forcing every one to spend internet every time they need to create reaact-app, waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to create a new react app and copy that every time. If there would be an official way to do it offline it would do almost the same thing but programatically (which also uses the same copying speed).

Comment: So, there is only one way, that is copying react-app, but it takes so much time that i might just create it while onlne :P